# MapKit: How do I get and set the collision frame rectangle of an annotation view?

Tags: ios, mapkit, collision-detection, mapkitannotation

`MKAnnotationView`s documentation says

**Managing Collisions Between Annotation Views**

```
var collisionMode: MKAnnotationView.CollisionMode
```

> The collision mode to use when interpreting the collision frame rectangle.

```
enum MKAnnotationView.CollisionMode
```

> Constants indicating how to interpret the collision frame rectangle of an annotation view.

I'd like to debug some collision behaviour that I don't understand.

So how do I get the `collision frame rectangle` that is referenced in the MapKit documentation? I'll probably try to draw this rectangle for visual debugging.

How do I set the `collision frame rectangle`? Maybe not directly, but which of the many involved views determines this rectangle?

This is the only reference of this term that I found in `MapKit`

**Edit**

Is this `collision frame rectangle` only used to make clusters or is it also used to hide the cluster with a lower display priority?

I have two `AnnotationViews` visually drawn on top of each other. One has `displayPriority = .required`, one has `displayPriority = .defaultHigh`. One should disappear. But where are their `collision frame rectangle`s? Do they really overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an explanation [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=UT9xDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA929&lpg=PA929&dq=mapkit%20collision%20frame%20rectangle&source=bl&ots=9wNPMeG24W&sig=ACfU3U3RXXYmsBsmksSwcokqZIJZVgqoNg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi288Sx4c3hAhWJ16QKHVYHCjcQ6AEwD3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=mapkit%20collision%20frame%20rectangle&f=false). It says:
`collisionMode`: An `MKAnnotationView.CollisionMode`. Two annotation views with the same `clusteringIdentifier` will be replaced by a cluster annotation if the map is zoomed out so far that they collide.
But what constitutes a collision between two annotation views? To know that, we need a collision edge. It might be:
`.rectangle`: The edge is the view’s frame.
`.circle`: The edge is the largest circle inscribable in and centered within the view’s frame.

EDIT:

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview) say: *The most efficient way to provide the content for an annotation view is to set its image property. The annotation view sizes itself automatically to the image you specify and draws that image for its contents*. Additionally, there are other properties that may influence the `frame` property. So it is this automatically adjusted `frame`that determines the collision frame.

Comment: I found the same reference before I asked this question. Which of the many views used by an AnnotationView is the one that is used? If it is the annotationView itself, what determines its frame?

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Thanks. This information is sufficient for me to debug. I set images for both and the images are drawn on top of each other.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, pls accept it so that the question is closed.

Comment: Yes, I was able to interpret the frames. (Still don't understand why Mapkit draws overlapping annotations in some edge cases - but that's a different question)

Comment: thanks for this @ReinhardMänner and guys.  it really is increedibly unclear how to just set the frame size.  if you just "set the frame" to say 0,0,100,100 in prepareForDisplay, that does *seem* to work.  But who knows.